# How to bind data in UWP apps directly from SQLite or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My question is that , how can i bind data into my UWP application directly from any Remote or Local SQL Server?

My Scenario is something like below.

```
<ListView Name="list_students">  
<!--Name the listView to refer-->  
<ListView.ItemTemplate>  
    <DataTemplate>  
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,20,0,0">  
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="100"></Image>  
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">  
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>  
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>  
            </StackPanel>  
        </StackPanel>  
    </DataTemplate>  
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in code behind i have something like this.

```
public class Student   
{  
    public int id   
    {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string Name   
    {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string Class   
    {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string RollNo   
    {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string ImagePath   
    {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *directly*?

Comment: I mean like is it possible to get the data directly and display it into my application without storing it in a list or in a collection ?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. This should in no language be possible **directly**

Comment: How will you get that data to begin with? were you storing it in a DataTable or were you using entity framework or linq? If you're using entity framework or linq to sql, you might be getting a list as a result of your query. You can then directly bind that to a view if you want to.